# "A RenderObject does not have any constraints before it has been laid out." Exception when opening the Flutter Widget Inspector in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout

I get this exception

> StateError('A RenderObject does not have any constraints before it has
> been laid out.');

but only when I open the SelectWidgetMode in VS Code or selecting a widget from the widget tree in the Widget Inspector

It seems to be VS Code specific problem, bc in Android Studio everything works fine

It seems to be related with "All Exceptions" check in the Breakpoints panel

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75596

Comment: I think this should be some kind of bug? with "All Exceptions" deselected, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you mentioned is being thrown by an internal function unrelated to your code.

The solution is to uncheck All Exceptions in the breakpoints panel.

Hope this helps someone.

[Like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxP3J.png)